# How to dequeue wp_get_custom_css in Twenty Twenty Theme

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

How to remove Additional CSS from loading. It loads as internal style sheet on every page. I am doing this but it is not working. if I

`print_r(wp_get_custom_css());`
It shows the same css. I want to disable it to load.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mywptheme_child_deregister_styles', 11 );
function mywptheme_child_deregister_styles() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'wp-custom-css' );
 
}
```

[image: Style]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `style` HTML is added by WordPress using [`wp_custom_css_cb()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_custom_css_cb/) and it's [hooked to `wp_head`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.5.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L299) like so:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_custom_css_cb', 101 );
```

Which adds the custom/additional CSS in the document `head`.

So if you don't want that to happen — or you'd rather add/load the CSS manually, you can add this to your theme `functions.php` file:

```php
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_custom_css_cb', 101 );
```

Comment: Thanks alot, you saved me :-)